# dyld: Library not loaded Reason: no suitable image found. Did find: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application…

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, code-signing

I am running into a very strange "loop" error.
I can fix each one separately, but not together

Here is the first error I get when I try to build an archive of my App.

```
"No signing identity found".
```

I can fix that with two ways: fastlane (cert + sigh) or by going through the whole Apple process.

However, once this is done, I run into the following issue:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/AMScrollingNavbar.framework/AMScrollingNavbar

Referenced from: /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/BAE2D723-6BD6-4D60-8008-C12CE8CCA72F/Qanda.app/Qanda

Reason: no suitable image found.  
Did find:
/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/BAE2D723-6BD6-4D60-8008-C12CE8CCA72F/Qanda.app/Frameworks/AMScrollingNavbar.framework/AMScrollingNavbar: mmap() errno=1 validating first page of '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/BAE2D723-6BD6-4D60-8008-C12CE8CCA72F/Qanda.app/Frameworks/AMScrollingNavbar.framework/AMScrollingNavbar'
/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/BAE2D723-6BD6-4D60-8008-C12CE8CCA72F/Qanda.app/Frameworks/AMScrollingNavbar.framework/AMScrollingNavbar: mmap() errno=1 validating first page of '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/BAE2D723-6BD6-4D60-8008-C12CE8CCA72F/Qanda.app/Frameworks/AMScrollingNavbar.framework/AMScrollingNavbar'
/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/BAE2D723-6BD6-4D60-8008-C12CE8CCA72F/Qanda.app/Frameworks/AMScrollingNavbar.framework/AMScrollingNavbar: mmap() errno=1 validating first page of '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/BAE2D723-6BD6-4D60-8008-C12CE8CCA72F/Qanda.app/Frameworks/AMScrollingNavbar.framework/AMScrollingNavbar'
```

The really weird thing is I don't actually have "AMScrollingNavbar" it in my Podfile.

Here is the Podfile list:

```
pod 'Alamofire'
pod 'SwiftyJSON'
pod 'SwiftVideoPlayer', :git => 'https://github.com/benjaminhorner/SwiftVideoPlayer.git', :branch => 'master'
pod 'FLAnimatedImage'
pod 'SDWebImage'
pod 'HanekeSwift', :git => 'https://github.com/meteochu/HanekeSwift.git', :branch => 'master'
pod 'SwiftyUserDefaults', :git => 'https://github.com/radex/SwiftyUserDefaults.git', :branch => 'master'
```

Now I did have AMScrollingNavBar installed at some point but I removed it from my pods. It seems like a reference to it is still there… but how do I remove it?

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated as I am going nuts with this.

Thanks!

Comment: This is weird. Duplicate your whole project somewhere else, add `pod 'AMScrollingNavbar', '1.3.6'` to your podfile, and reinstall pods. I say duplicate instead just so nothing gets messed up **just** incase

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project and deleting DerivedData folder?

Comment: Ya you could have had it referenced from something else. I "twitch click" `shift-command-k` right before `command-s` followed by `command-r`

Comment: @euvs: Yes I have. didn't change a thing.

Comment: @iStoke: what do you mean by duplicating the project? Starting from afresh to see what happens? And I am not sure I get your point about cleaning, then saving, the running…

Comment: First I said duplicate your entire project and run these tests (if you don't use Git!). Just to make sure my comment doesn't screw up your project! And the clean-save-run is what I hit all the time. Clean your project every once in a while. It prevents errors in your project. Like if you just deleted a file or something, keeps the connections and links to it managed for instance

Comment: @iStoke. OK I get it now. I DO use Git ;) Adding ‘pod 'AMScrollingNavbar', '1.3.6'‘ does fix it… until I archive the project. Then the same issue comes along. However, I DON'T want AMScrollingNavbar as I am not using it.

Comment: Good good, Git all day every day. And that sucks, well I figured maybe it doesn't like not having that as a dependency or something.

Comment: Here is a video review of a very good set up for Mac devs using Xcode. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=pZP1Gymu4wk - it will save you SO MUCH PAIN AND AGONY that identities and provisioning profiles bring you

Comment: Put your developer profiles and signing identities in your project folder - That way you can import the profile everytime you pull down from the repo (if you use multiple computers or have deep freeze)

Comment: Thanks for the video, but I already use GIT + Bitbucket + Fastlane to handle all my certificates etc. This is far from being my first app but it is the first time I have encountered this kind of "loop" error. I guess I will try starting from scratch and doing it step by step.

Answer (score 1):

This is **not a solution** but a **workaround**, however, it "solved" my problem. I started the project again from scratch, reinstalling cocoapods etc. Not a good solution but desperate matters require desperate actions.

If anyone comes up with a solution or even an explanation, I would be glad to hear about it.